# How do I communicate from JS to Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I'm creating a hybrid app and I'm trying to figure out how to pass some data from the WKWebView to the native app.

I've been trying to figure this out for days and I can't seem to find anything! There seems to be very little info online about this, and everything I do find, is the other way around (Swift to JS, not JS to Swift).

I've tried using URL variables, but the Webview has to reload for Swift to recognize that it changed. I tried using [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler), but I can't find any good documentation about it, and it seems very complicated.

There must be some easy way to accomplish this.
Any ideas?

I would be really grateful to anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not that complicated actually.

Firstly you have to add the script message handler into the content controller.

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.add(self, name: "derp") //name is the key you want the app to listen to.
```

Next up you have to assign the content controller into the configuration.

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController
```

then you need to assign the configuration to your web view.

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: config) //set your own frame
```

and for the JS side.

```
var message = {'fruit':'apple'};
window.webkit.messageHandlers.derp.postMessage(message);
```

Lastly you have to let your view controller (I'm assuming that the webView is in a view controller) conform to the WKScriptMessageHandler protocol. I've added the rest of the codes into a sample view controller as requested.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(self, name: "derp")

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config) //you can consider using auto layout though
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        //load your url here 
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        //handle script messages here
        //message.name is "derp"
        //message.body is ["fruit":"apple"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to IOS. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more on the Swift part? I'm not sure where to add the script message handler, or where to assign the configuration. Can you please show me a complete viewcontroller.swift file?

Comment: Everything is working great. But I one more issue I can't seem to solve. In your code you created a new WebView then added it the the subview. However, I already have an existing web view. How do assign your 'configuration' to my current web view without creating a new one? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Maybe you can try setting the userContentController directly. webView.configuration.userContentController = contentController

Comment: For some reason,  it only works when I create a new web view and add it to the subview. But if I try setting the userContentController directly to an existing webview, it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. All it was is this... let contentController = self.webView.configuration.userContentController;
        contentController.add(self, name: "derp");

Comment: @nachshonf sorry i did not access SO till now. glad that it's working now!