# Youtube video unresponsive after requesting current duration Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, swiftui, youtube

I am building a Tiktok clone app using YouTube shorts. I give the users the ability to hold down on the screen then drag to any duration in the video.

In order to do so I have to keep track of the current duration of the video. I set a repeating timer for every second that calls the **sendCurrentTime** function. This function communicates back to Swift by throwing an error that contains the current duration.

When I use this method and go through about 20 videos at least one will be unresponsive and auto play then auto pause a few times before completely freezing. It seems like every time the **sendCurrentTime** function is called it toggles the playing state of the video until the video is just unresponsive. When I go through a bunch of videos without this function being called I don't experience this behavior. Why does this happen?

```
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var currentTime: Double

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        webview.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(web: webview)
        
        return webview
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                if self.parent.isPlaying {
                    webView.evaluateJavaScript("sendCurrentTime()", completionHandler: { (_, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            let string = "\(error)"
                            do {
                                let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "Current Time: (\\d+)", options: [])
                                if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count)) {
                                    if let range = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string) {
                                        let videoDuration = string[range]
                                        self.parent.currentTime = Double(videoDuration) ?? 0.0
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch { print("") }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(web: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = false;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            function sendCurrentTime() {
                var videoState = player.getPlayerState();
                if (videoState === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    const currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
                    var errorMessage = "Current Time: " + currentTime;
                    throw new Error(errorMessage);
                }
            }
        
        </script>
        """
        
        web.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        web.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing a JavaScript error in the `sendCurrentTime` function to send back the current time to Swift: that does not seem to be the most efficient or reliable way to facilitate JavaScript to Swift communication. It is probable that triggering an error interrupts the playback because it is caught by the WebKit error handling mechanisms.

You can avoid throwing errors by using [`WKScriptMessageHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler) to facilitate the communication between your JavaScript and Swift code:

- Replace your `sendCurrentTime` JavaScript function with one that uses `webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage` to send the current time to Swift.
- Modify your `Coordinator` class to conform to `WKScriptMessageHandler` and implement the `userContentController(_:didReceive:)` method to receive messages from JavaScript.

You can see that kind of solution in "[How do I communicate from JS to Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861130/6309)" and in [iOS WKWebView Communication Using Javascript and Swift](https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/ios-wkwebview-communication-using-javascript-and-swift-ee077e0127eb) from [Mark Water](https://medium.com/@mark.waters/about)

In your case:

```swift
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "observe")
    webview.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

    loadInitialContent(web: webview)
    
    return webview
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    // existing code

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "observe", let currentTime = message.body as? Double {
            parent.currentTime = currentTime
        }
    }

    // existing code
}
```

Update your JavaScript code to send the message instead of throwing an error:

```js
function sendCurrentTime() {
    var videoState = player.getPlayerState();
    if (videoState === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        const currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
        webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(currentTime);
    }
}
```

By using `WKScriptMessageHandler`, you create a more direct and reliable channel for sending messages from your JavaScript code to your Swift code, which could help to prevent the freezing issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks this got ride of that bug. Would you know how to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062686/swift-enter-full-screen-in-youtube-embed-video-programmatically

Comment: Hey Von, finally done with my app. It's available on the IOS App Store in the link below if you want to take a look. My personal email is ak3zaidan@gmail.com if you want to give me a critique or recommend some changes. I appreciate all your help. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hustles/id6452946210

Comment: @ahmed Nice, congrats on the launch!

Comment: Von the following question is quite big maybe you can help with it or know someone that can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248619/swift-swift-ui-fix-bugs-in-tiktok-clone-on-ios-app-hustles

Comment: Von the question above was closed, you should be able to view it though. If you can help still email me at ak3zaidan@gmail.com. Id be willing to pay.

Comment: @ahmed I see. I did upvote it and voted to be reopened.

Comment: @ahmed Would [this gist](https://gist.github.com/VonC/0115dc1ea6db4f4d1e8acdc061a2c35c)  help?

Comment: Thanks a lot you're amazing. I feel embarrassed to keep asking but would you mind helping with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257244/simple-swift-ui-view-bug-when-using-header-uicollectionviewflowlayout

Comment: @ahmed Sure. First, since [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77248619/6309) was reopened ([by me, amongst others](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77248619/timeline)), can I put my gist as an answer there?