# Swift + Swift UI - Fix bugs in TikTok clone on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, youtube

I am the owner of a social media app on the iOS app store, and my platform includes a TikTok like service that displays YouTube shorts. The UI of this service is quite buggy (bugs included below) and doesn't function properly. Apple has requested that I fix these issues immediately. How can I improve the functionality of this service? My knowledge in web scraping and WebViews is quite limited.

Here is the problem I want to fix: screen flashes white then black as video loads, I would like to have the video cover show with a loading icon above until the video is ready to play.

**Single View**

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import UIKit

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var viewIsShowing = false
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: VideoModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black //so background always black
            
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, isChangingTime: $isChangingTime, totalLength: $totalLength, currentTime: $currentTime, viewIsShowing: $viewIsShowing)

            Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)       //disable any interaction with youtube video
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()         //play pause video
                }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onDisappear {                  //stop playing when view leaves
            isVideoPlaying = false
            viewIsShowing = false
        }
        .onAppear {                     //try and play the video when view appears
            if viewModel.selected == link {
                viewIsShowing = true
                isVideoPlaying = true
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.selected, perform: { _ in       //when the current video link changes play or pause
            if viewModel.selected == link {
                viewIsShowing = true
                isVideoPlaying = true
            } else if viewModel.selected != link {
                viewIsShowing = false
                isVideoPlaying = false
            }
        })
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var viewIsShowing: Bool

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "observe")

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webConfiguration.userContentController = userContentController

        let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        loadInitialContent(web: webview)
        
        return webview
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        var jsString = """
        isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false");
        watchPlayingState();
        """
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler  {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage){
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {     //try and force play the video
            if self.parent.viewIsShowing {
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReady()", completionHandler: nil)
                
                //randomly try again incase took some time to load
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: false) { _ in
                    webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReadySec()", completionHandler: nil)
                }
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { _ in
                    webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReadySec()", completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(web: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = false;
            var ready = false;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {      //restart video on end
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            function clickReady() {
                if (ready) {
                    player.playVideo();
                }
            }
            function clickReadySec() {
                if (ready) {
                    var videoState = player.getPlayerState();
                    if (videoState !== YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                        player.playVideo();
                    }
                }
            }
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying && ready) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        </script>
        """
        
        web.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        web.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

**Tab View containing single videos**

```
import SwiftUI

struct AllVideoView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: VideoModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom, .top])
            TabView(selection: $viewModel.selected){
                ForEach(viewModel.VideosToShow){ video in
                    SingleVideoView(link: video).tag(video)
                }
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true), height: widthOrHeight(width: false))
            }
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: false), height: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

class VideoModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selected = ""
    
    //Data to test
    @Published var VideosToShow: [String] = ["iYebqpQ_EBA", "ZVAo11HS2lc", "j7f704_t6-U", "sZVW6dJk7_I", "8v7Tx2re5Rs", "xn90M86iUGw", "XTg3S-Ncr3I", "gJodMlgxyuY", "4Crbau26xdM", "wjSrqX_InUc", "4vaoZ0k7WC4", "wm-i3C2xi6E", "LOdHJKf8SaY", "T8SDP6rm-0k", "uIb5nrsWvxQ", "Qpbr5H34E_I", "MumEnIr_2vU", "6sTW7Q2uvo0", "ErnrcsM1CIk", "EuTUcRjtLbI", "xrovQjCSgtM", "DdlFT6ZPIR0", "HcpuMXsgMfI", "Xxk4mdojVTQ", "NJue1Wh4GZg", "xECgbg3SKg4", "pmqznJ1Pr64", "KKYplXrrOW0", "YuaeouCu8z4", "--Ay4om9zdQ", "950tFcmRtMc", "k56Ry6FLuYU", "QDpYHqDPYe0", "8JiB2ywr59c", "vAXR73OYU7c", "4tdS35_jUNc", "KYZeNx451Eo", "iEQQpdNbjdo", "KqwWLwKXUSA", "IDAmXhMj6Lo", "kd2g1xBs90g", "LFOIqZVv1Rc", "zCIeG6ht7jQ", "4co3RUJeebw", "Fb8YYJdgnmE", "ID1tfz4Hd1Q", "qSWzWYPOENY", "U-uIZLzgvfI", "R9r22u2gs_c", "3K0M69Npb1I", "DiHU8BJJ6jw", "4ZVsp4EkMb0", "SpHf4eBDjCk", "Rfudjg0jkvo", "EIFy41gYeVQ", "buQhVDlgbRg", "Rlz0vCw3bYs", "5Tv5xBn1AoI", "7Tv4RjbBSe8", "yhaFe_RzM14", "FDeMoHpyjJE", "h-RmBQ-GYY0", "e0rh5hgJJM0", "hjA4X_crpks", "wAVQ4u4V6vY", "NawgIgsyLTA", "OFtoXhXNEa0", "kPC9JW9c2Ro", "uhsy5vzmgls", "_Lm9ahDneqA", "u6Y6rbblFek", "U-C_XW8sZl4", "RHqGlX3lIEo", "yl0AOc45tQg", "C2V8K5yMBdo", "j8ROZ7-aIE8", "FODrGNH1SjA", "JYpWudy4jaQ", "QvqyeUaExNo", "WDYG2DwfJDk", "zz2Fxkf9u8M", "8bFp8CNyEus", "oLdPRJ8qI84", "dowoyaGmTgE", "GtLbiDqrs-0", "MyoH8blacsE", "7LS879KOdK0", "D4Qpeliwk4w", "nmMI3BM1ea8", "VGWgFary4Es", "9qqfxtOiTJ0", "Vt61xtJilHA", "URHFPuSNvt8", "pzX-PSaIV-c", "QaK8XcvvOEE", "pgk3d2VNbbo", "vKtZ5yqKY9A", "lVl-1ZTN8UY", "iKX79_6ZVpQ", "6FNjp772iyg", "ppaktgRUw4M", "qaf7uO5Hs0E", "3PfBSRfDa-8", "OGGLLoSyBCw", "_GXpYnTjjCY", "TDACktZbs9s", "qRzix60msYs", "UUBKHJB5xm0", "tuFsPpkyjes", "woSAr1TY-rs", "3mCkBvpIuYc", "O2YoEcY51SY", "af3dkkGqIH4", "Clo8frpXQRk", "JrCaYLvpTTo", "ag8MAvd6t94", "VOJVNyUtjUI", "ye5rxzDS_Bo", "SAZtnEuCnj0", "gO7bDxe-tWI", "iINSdcdhjBQ", "ysNIsT-1emU", "y97KR2XjMHA", "PkEeowOtqgE", "Z5NsgZQjjoc", "CeoIIi6oJiU", "-yMmZT0XyBg", "B7Uz78okItk", "IZieI2VnpXM", "Vsb4yho_hTk", "Lu4Ie_lJsKg", "NBgOY-kHWVQ", "YnFI3IS8duA", "3fIWRHQYRb8", "prLyItjvb0w", "-gSbmK1eN_Q", "3Zkfq9JYaf4", "2CvCIFPdgMo", "hUsDOf8s61o", "ha2_x5eJ1OY", "sqJ5fEqmh1w", "Q8nUj8EH8qM", "TXLA-qtWlj4", "uFu8YxtoZaU", "JTQ-zkZ9WQQ", "bYuLW07tGmI", "bCPuLceW-yE", "ot0d3ZgPrN8", "m0myvDUD5Js", "HJQ4TiCFvUY", "TS6xiAV1qHQ", "-38yIw4IhAY", "x-n0FwD8HFs", "uwbZ4UWbuhQ", "EhuAMPjuEks", "Nk5HgYdTRdg", "ztLTqCjrXrc", "q0VUZ2hAIuw", "S_vOu6oqCDE", "sh0hHSq5Ogc", "oyswMIUFr4w", "zoSjLJqJPDQ", "BLTnIBQJlFc", "pUYDN-stzck", "g1ucPFztCrc", "u4Pav23IzS4", "7eaAN0X_evA", "GIRrfccZvLI", "fVP7IansDAI", "41QxPIfWFN8", "7kFhNLEI7yY", "NH2OI2Q0q14", "as2WgzniPVo", "rjiteE2rKFs", "yz2TumE1ws0", "d-XwLHM8sFE", "uN4h4OmtfEk", "u2-7hhlMb6w", "-JaSHN3aIyY", "pZTjhMxas_s", "zN8fSWxHxVc", "D_uXLM3VJYs", "nk0hOKS_zfA", "EaImidqT0xQ", "7PlSHvyqh70", "epbrJg-LTOE", "9gE7MOnmHfs", "F5m2Qg2cst4", "kikGvjKFN8Q", "Kbvk8T6QXBE", "k-IXHTPWV8M", "uGiclr_zW2M", "rGIL7Yal2WA", "7-_LCq2UTA8", "VRvBcnQ7Yyo", "5R9zmI5Mbrc", "HaUm23dTR5g", "otUIqpojXqA", "5Jq0IlNzvM4", "21EofWX0uuo", "PacSMXd1FIc", "sEWZ7TPXXDM", "zbElpS_OiGc", "0jSmuCKvj7U", "uoiQChfa-c8", "jv1IKf_NQ50", "j4Yl886jRSU", "E6JSDl70zEY", "-fyklDM48ig", "7amjvAwvXes", "agwGF1FeWOQ", "tTft0J__BrA", "n_rf3Jjclrw", "gJDKloPhiMk", "vK3MG9yhn4o", "-UGDDKQE2FI", "a5RNe4vITws", "gf1Bvx6oVKw", "DCwSyZGQbEQ", "7G6ipKZfeLM", "UftB2CCWyHs", "Uf2FAF1rSJQ", "YC9hLAinWig", "g-5wvzYR8MY", "UsUoqDLJOnA", "BtkwBEts0Jg", "cKDbx1Udj_Q", "ax7kwHO4fvc", "xMYdyz5JteE", "VZjj1D3DGrw", "fW7dfJ7_PkE", "sEFUk8sb6vk", "4sTxfxxEZW0", "l2k1vzNno3A", "ZYe0k_dk5D4", "IBMshfQ-jCo", "pYJjIzj-t4c", "vK5riR3lbIM", "TiBAmEW03mM", "pLBPbJcJ_F4", "PQLJhhpXIDs", "ZRSjBQ_qIhE", "V9zTAsfN9Bw", "4dqiSzf-y-I", "L16S2yCRo10", "HctLr25JFx4", "l5WyvXvYRzc", "sbYofIDT4Y0", "3WEPgIitq6Y", "GBjoifXMkEc", "D7cdGKevHYk", "wU0oqTncwSc", "uCIYARYeaF8", "fzChmE4wzME", "dNmFhyMzckg", "bbvQBEtAJrU", "GMC57RwqPDg", "CRueXlxg24s", "2lpcP8LyZrs", "Y8n5LmBz8Vk", "WkfEO9aoNuc", "Vi1jtwUc0kU", "irVXM6JDUQg", "o1XPcaokECE", "5bMPf_E1-Vw", "RYMXdvLOIls", "Ksb5gWSJPQ8", "hEP5XqEu7P4", "rf5qRQugqgY", "ndzHTk1tJtk", "0MMQSjoLIVc", "_-YsXJ72eeo", "zBP4TsOWbH0", "LecyAUI93c0", "C0OA0WcN0BY", "DAKxPMg6oPw", "UeSum0pCm_U", "L8GxXFW_y6Q", "Nm0WQ26euoc", "dwEIVP6kKLY", "kd2g1xBs90g", "rlYBLoYUiPQ", "2BqPHZWT86Q", "T9ZuTZRxgag", "epRrztb3VHc", "_V0oZOOHvOw", "rLlbIz-UsW0", "U_eoUo7tEAE", "LHpUQdQDtyQ", "GGbzmEoTPWA", "nxmKRgO_a44", "iuB4OwPTa7M", "MI8nv441Q78", "pkETcBX15Ns", "A9xx98UqDd8", "2LTR5SstIhA", "OdAPkzyetZY", "B_SMTxXIAT4", "516ESehbjcw", "GqCBB_9drtg", "1mwybHblSoU", "AwPcbIGG9DQ", "9C7Rjy3GgqU", "AquwGe-LRNI", "l3QDF8KfMlQ", "oxWowAGygq4", "qkkptG9UXg4", "fudFlhI43JQ", "6IoJ3iaT_2Q", "hTNADe1fGIs", "L6z3TZaTKl8", "dlXqMvzye24", "8iXzfysURSc", "ukBKppVJYLo", "sPkkWBckt44", "ecB8x_pP-8M", "xjMAlSs5Ayg", "tna_mHHtChw", "https://youtube.com/shorts/xyhY92K0RDI?si=DZAYC6285acLMJud", "ASEZtFsbjVE", "HFpHOoPa3yo", "DJvQzI9bae4", "-uUP5YUBJ-0", "0sx9QHubgqc", "7OeKeFisbgg", "6Kp30WYyF5M", "K709BAWgqs4", "H5vLWyWMBgA", "iDgetgvbk7E", "xwakzmjkNe0", "ddjQMQyOqJU", "IThk6vqrVs8", "0cKQsIUOXx4", "CkCpplHbDzs", "dOQsXA30RWU", "01P0hQQgq-c", "Mt4hOuodhvo", "MSG_J4nZoA0", "TndspK834ms", "ivLRbslmuzE", "33fsguWtdXo", "ulQHG4CtIcc", "Jp9zpUtafxA", "HWy4w8QWrJc", "uvRWJr-WUTs", "MhlOPtLxBM0", "qvBaaK8voyw", "EW7FTWV1H0c", "X220GWe_lmQ", "3oy2hklCdZM", "Yzs1NecYPPw", "PTWTkfzQI5o", "0zEyTOb7Tr0", "KbzlC01D83c", "FQNP-gbyjZk", "JMWuo1XylM4", "t9_Nz91jxmY", "iYtdYc_WLM0", "Ak1lmnMzf-Y", "9sPRNYitLLY", "KpjTXmm7pGE", "K9Ym44tJbQE", "lg_VwVnpqIE", "kv9PCqLj3vo", "aSd1IQNm4_s", "gjCz0BBGtQE", "2Rl9TivKS34", "HArdqJHadtE", "Xs0mbQUy9qg", "5ksMWUPhG3M", "JnDR5lQMYb4", "Iwck0KLLTAw", "-Z9d9-4I21s", "f6W8DsmIC5k", "ibRhoFfbgZI", "KoW3Qr_Uttk", "HFgadwtV2U0", "tPgSLUBxwlo", "hJtrIFhHoiE", "q0_53pX1V40", "sQ64plrMdjY", "UIeOjGR1ols", "y2PAOVxHyzw", "ENfQ5Q9hzd4", "S81byfkCbzc", "TBNfnC8lj2c", "2X-pqstQ9Mg", "BlEWAH17wus", "DLKn3np-QXA", "M1jGiFhPyvc", "uaxvB2YcccA", "aJIA0FM-ko4", "1CZgcxiSS4w", "HjFoOMpMQ6c", "IpLvmKbWDEQ", "220CEbaowoA", "CK2cCr4At1o", "cjA2TVjx6Xg", "wY8IjPPWqbg", "5o7Fe1P078s", "VwQtD-ZVbzs", "CUPvgecdsck"]
}
```

Comment: Please ask about _one_ issue only and make sure to describe that single issue clearly and only include code relevant to that issue.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the bugs are all interrelated into how the web view is set up.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I wouldn't be asking this question if I knew what the source code of these bugs are. How would I "only include code relevant to that issue". Kind of defeating the purpose of what a question is.

Comment: Please do not ask for your app to be downloaded so that readers can see the problem. Shortly you will fix the problem, upload a new version of the app, and future readers will then not be able to make sense of this question. I have thus removed that part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The videos are embedded within a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) and the relevant UI components are built using SwiftUI. But the screen flashes white then black as the video loads, and the desired outcome is to have the video cover show with a loading icon until the video is ready to play.

For that, you might consider a **video cover** and **loading indicator**:

- To display a loading indicator and a video cover, you can introduce a new SwiftUI `View` that overlays on top of your `SingleVideoView`. That overlay view can contain a loading indicator and an image view for displaying the video cover.
- Utilize the [`ZStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/zstack/) to stack the overlay view on top of the `SmartReelView`.
- Hide the overlay view once the video is ready to play. That can be done by checking the `isPlaying` state or by introducing a new state to specifically handle the loading status.

```swift
struct LoadingOverlayView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
            ImageView()  // Assume this view displays your video cover
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.black //so background always black
        
        SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, isChangingTime: $isChangingTime, totalLength: $totalLength, currentTime: $currentTime, viewIsShowing: $viewIsShowing)
        
        if !isVideoPlaying {
            LoadingOverlayView()
        }
        
        Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)  //disable any interaction with youtube video
        
        Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
            .onTapGesture {
                isVideoPlaying.toggle()  //play pause video
            }
    }
    // rest of your code
}
```

---

In your JavaScript code within `SmartReelView`, you may consider introducing a mechanism to notify your Swift code when the video is ready to play. That can be done using the YouTube Iframe Player API's `onReady` event.
Make use of the [`WKScriptMessageHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler/) protocol to receive messages from your JavaScript code and update your SwiftUI view accordingly.

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: '100%',
        videoId: '\(link)',
        playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
        events: {
            'onReady': function(event) {
                // Notify your Swift code that the video is ready
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage("ready");
            },
            'onStateChange': function(event) {
                if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {      //restart video on end
                    player.seekTo(0);
                    player.playVideo();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```swift
class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler  {
    var parent: SmartReelView

    init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "observe" && message.body as! String == "ready" {
            // Update your SwiftUI view to hide the loading overlay
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.isPlaying = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    // rest of your code
}
```

That would create a new overlay view to handle the loading indicator and video cover, along with tweaking the JavaScript and Swift interaction to hide the overlay once the video is ready to play. It is essential to ensure that the video cover image is available and properly displayed within the `ImageView`.